# Forecasting with GARCH(1,1) using ARMA(1,1) forecasting error

Tags: r, arima

I am currently using the package `rugarch` to predict future volatility using out of sample data and keep on getting the errors:

When using the spec:

```
ugarchforecast(ug_spec, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 499, data = ForeRFTSE[1:758, , drop = FALSE], out.sample = 500)
```

Error:

```
ugarchforecast-->error: parameters names do not match specification
Expected Parameters are: mu ar1 ma1 omega alpha1 beta1
```

or when use the fitted Parameter:

```
ugarchforecast(RFTSE_GARCH, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 499, data = ForeRFTSE[1:758, , drop = FALSE], out.sample = 500)
```

Error:

```
Error in .sgarchforecast(fitORspec = fitORspec, data = data, n.ahead = n.ahead,  : 

ugarchforecast-->error: n.roll must not be greater than out.sample!
```

This is my ug_spec code

```
ug_spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",
                                            garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                      mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,1),
                                        include.mean=TRUE),
                      distribution.model = "norm"  )
```

This is my RFTSE_GARCH

```
RFTSE_GARCH = ugarchfit(spec = ug_spec,solver = 'hybrid', data = RFTSE)
```